# Unable to compile Secure Authentication Using SPNEGO Java GSS Mechanism

Tags: java, security, kerberos, gssapi

I am trying to run the example GssSpNegoClient.java at the java tutorial [Secure Authentication Using SPNEGO Java GSS Mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part5.html) and I am not able to compile because of a line:

```
Jaas.loginAndAction("client", action);
```

The compiler is complaining that `Jaas` not found. I am sure I've all the imports in place from the tutorial. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe  you need to do [step 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/lab/part1.html) before you do step 5.

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that %JAVA_HOME%/bin is in the system PATH.